# Jackson exlude extended class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have class:

```
public class User implements Body {

    private Integer userId;
    private String userName;
    private String emailId;

    //getter and setter

}
```

I want with Jackson mapper exclude **Body** class because I get error

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 User user = new User;
 String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
```

How I can convert object to JSON with exclude all extended or implementation class? I need convert only User class without Body

My super class have many public method like this:

```
public final Enumeration method(String email) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error");
        }
    

    public final Object method(String name) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error");
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to modify the Body class?

Comment: no, I can't modify Body class

Answer (score 0):

Simply annotate the class you are serializing and list the properties to exclude.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"bodyPropertyA", "bodyPropertyB", "bodyPropertyC"})
public class User implements Body {

    private Integer userId;
    private String userName;
    private String emailId;
}
```

Comment: another way you can edit your ObjectMapper (not suggested)

Comment: I have hundreds objects I can't do this method. I need another way eg exclude one class because my all object extended one class

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a filter to exclude parent fields. Here is a test:

```
public class JacksonTest {
  @Test
  public void excludeParent() throws JsonProcessingException {
  ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter theFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter
      .serializeAllExcept("name","phone");
    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
      .addFilter("filterPerson", theFilter);
    objectMapper.setFilterProvider(filters);
    final User user = new User("email1",12);
    user.setName("personName");
    user.setPhone("12345");
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user));
  }

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonFilter("filterPerson")
class User extends Person{
  String email;
  int age;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Person{
  String name;
  String phone;
}
```

console:

```
{"email":"email1","age":12}
```

Comment: I got JsonMappingException I think because I extenden not POJO class, so I need avoid all class –

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@JsonIgnore
public interface HiddenBody extends Body {
}

public class User implements HiddenBody {
    //
}
```

The [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) says everything should still compile and execute OK.